# WCF authorization not work

Tags: web-services, wcf

In my WCF4.5 https web service I want to set authorization to specific users/groups, I.e. I only want certain domain users or groups to be allowed to call my service.

In my web.config I have added the following as a simple test to see if every user is disallowed:

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

In my bindings section I have a:

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
</security>
```

and a similar entry in my client.

However, when I run my client, it is allowed. So I'm figuring I'm missing something out?

I've read various websites and they either simply mention the above or go into a whole detail about all sorts without a meaningful answer or require hard coding of security in code.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
<allow roles="DOMAIN\Group"/>
```

Otherwise you deny ALL the users by using `<deny users="*" />`

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
        <allow roles="DOMAIN\Group"/>
        <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```